# Can I force the CustomUnboundColumnData event to be raised?

Tags: c#, gridview, devexpress

I have a usercontrol that has custom unbound data columns in a gridView. I want to retain view state when switching between screens in my app in terms of selected tabs and focused rows etc.

When I do this switch and restore that view state, my custom data is gone and the CustomUnboundColumnData event handler does not get used at all.

Is there a way to raise the CustomUnboundColumnData event for this gridView after I restore my view state?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found a work around.  I was refreshing my data in this grid view anyway. However, the few columns that had unbound data needed to be re-added to the grid before refreshing this data.

Comment: Can you be please more specific? :-) "refreshing my data" is said in a very generic way.

Answer (score 1):

Call the [`RefreshRow`](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_RefreshRowtopic) or [`RefreshRowCell`](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_RefreshRowCelltopic) methods, passing a row handle and optionally a column.

Comment: Hey there :) Tried this, it didn't do what I wanted it to.

Comment: @Cor: I've done this myself; it does work.  Please show us your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the ASPxGridView, I would suggest that you turn off the [EnableRowsCache](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_EnableRowsCachetopic) property.  One more solution is to call the ASPxGridView's DataBind method explicitly within the Page_Init method.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but I'm not using ASPxGridView. It's just an XtraGrid.Views.GridView